# Can I use Javascript to find a table row by its rowIndex?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table with multiple rows and columns. I also have a variable named userRowIndex that has the index of a certain row saved in it. I want to be able to make this whole row content editable using just JavaScript and my userRowIndex variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript Library?

Comment: No, I'm not using a JS library, and I'm not too keen on using one either

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector` with the `nth-child` CSS selector to achieve this with vanilla JS.

Comment: So select all the rows, grab the one at the index.

Comment: @Amy I like your thinking there. I've actually just found a way to save the id of the row instead so I can just use the id selector, but thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');
// whatever your userRowIndex is : 
var userRowIndex  = 1;

rows[userRowIndex].className = 'red';
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'> .red{color:red;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>One</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Two</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Three</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This method is good but on a very long table it could cause lag

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example how a particular `td` can be make editable using `rowIndex`

```js
// get the table
var getTable = document.querySelector("#demotable");
// adding event listener
getTable.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // current cell index
  var col = event.target.cellIndex,
   // get index of row from td
    row = event.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
  // set the contenteditable property to it
  this.rows[row].cells[col].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true')
})
```

```html
<table border id="demotable">


  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Also note one `td` can be editable at a time.Even though the entire row can be make editable but only one cell can be changed at one time

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster:

```
function getRowByIndex(userRowIndex)
{
    var rows = null;
    var row = null;

    try
    {
        rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');

        if(rows!=null)
        {
            // This uses 0 based indexing, so assume that the passed value is in that range
            row = rows[userRowIndex];
        }

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("getRowByIndex Error:  " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return row;
}
```